# Camel File polling - moved file to processed path without processing

Tags: apache-camel

Below is my camel file route with a delay set to 2000, which continuosly polls  a folder `{{ResponsePath}}` and moves it to path `{{ResponseProcessed}}` on completion and to `{{ResponseFailed}}` on failure

```
<route id="fileProcessor">
    <from uri="file://{{ResponsePath}}?preMove={{ResponseInProgressPath}}/${header.CamelFileNameOnly}&amp;move={{ResponseProcessed}}/${header.CamelFileNameOnly}&amp;moveFailed={{ResponseFailed}}/${header.CamelFileNameOnly}&amp;delay=2000"/>
    <doTry>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <log message="Response ${body}"/>
        <bean ref="fileProcessorBean" method="processFile" />
        <log message="File Processed Successfully"/>
    <doCatch>
        <exception>com.test.CustomFileException
        </exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
    </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
```

The problem Im facing is on loading multiple files to the polling folder, some of the files are processed and moved to PROCESSED path and some are directly moved to PROCESSED path without processing

Comment: Hi! Your exception handler would appear to result in everything being a success. If you remove the exception handler, do some of them go to failure?

Comment: Hi. Yes it moves to failed folder path too. Would be gratefull to know why some of the files to be processed moved to processed without  being processed

Answer (score 1):

As @Screwtape already commented, all files are moved to PROCESSED path because you **catch and handle exceptions**.

- A file is consumed
- It is processed in the try block
- If all goes well, it is moved by the file consumer to the PROCESSED path
- If an exception occurs, it is handled by the catch block
- Therefore **the exception does not reach the file consumer**
- So the file consumer think all went well and moves it to the PROCESSED path

Remove the whole doTry/doCatch block so that exceptions reach the file consumer and it will move these files to the FAILED path.

Comment: Understood and taken care. But the file route is deployed in multiple tomcat loadbalanced servers. And the paths are shared folders, Is there something else missing? Even after removing try catch, same resulted

Comment: OK, then it would be interesting to know if this also happens when you have only 1 consumer. Just to know if it is a problem of the route or a problem of concurrency.

Comment: Actually the fact, that you are using multiple servers is really important. You are using no `readLock` option. See docs and choose one which is relevant for your environment. But you will have hard choice, if your shared drive does not support distributed file locks. Most of the locks cannot work reliably with competitive consumers from shared drive.  If you need something 100% safe, you will probably end up with `readLock=idempotent` and some `idempotentRepository` which supports atomic operations on distributed map (infinispan, hazelcast,...).